# super keyword outside a class context?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

There's this file, `app.rb` and it contains the following:

```
def initialize(*args)
  super
  @action = :add
end
```

It's not inside a class. Why does it have a `super` keyword? The file is [here](https://github.com/gchef/nginx-cookbook/blob/master/resources/app.rb#L23).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file will be used to create a new **"Lightweight"** resource class. The defined methods will be copied there without any changes. So **super** makes perfect sense, because the newly generated class will inherit from Chef::Resource.

Check out more on [Lightweight resources and providers (LWRP)](http://wiki.opscode.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7274964)